# Car engine got wet through low water pass - any potential unseen damage?

Tags: engine, alternator, electronics, air-filter

Last night it was raining hard. There was a bridge that was flooded but I couldn't tell because the ruler marker sign was knocked down. As I approached it the car got deeper and deeper into water. When I saw rushing water at the top of the rails of the bridge ahead of me I realized I was in a lot of trouble.

I had water up to my headlights in my 2013 Corolla. I was able to turn my car around and get out. The engine almost cut out a few times. I truly believe it was the Lord Jesus Christ, by his grace, that I was able to get out of that low water passing. It was really a traumatic event and scary.

Today I looked at my engine compartment and I see that where the dried dirty brown water got over all the engine compartments. The license plate was bent completely upwards. Besides a musky dirty smell in my car(don't know why because the carpet didn't get wet), is there any unseen damage that could have happened to my engine parts? Should I replace any filters(I just recently replaced the engine filter before this happened)?

Comment: This has been asked before, might be work searching...

Comment: Where in the heck do you live that there are bridges like that?

Comment: San Antonio, Texas.... Some rural areas